# Pass in styles from stylesheet into custom component in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, rxjs

I am trying to pass in styles into my custom Component. They seem to work fine if I manually pass them in like `style={{width: 100}}` but if I pass them in via stylesheet... they return random numbers into my custom component.

Home Component:

```
return (
    <View>
        <CustomButton style={styles(theme).button} />
    </View>
);

const styles = (theme: Theme) =>
  StyleSheet.create({
    button: {
      width: 100
    }
  });
```

**CustomButton:**

```
interface ButtonProps {
    style?: object;
}

export const CustomButton: React.FC<ButtonProps> = ({ ...props }: ButtonProps) => {
    console.log(props.style); // returns random numbers like 402, 411, etc

    return (
      <View>
        <Button
          style={{
            marginVertical: 5,
            ...props.style
          }}
        >Test</Button>
      </View>
    );
  };
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are seeing is an optimisation done by `StyleSheet`. What you are seeing as a "random number" is the `object id` of the style object `button`.

You can see the actual object by using `StyleSheet.flatten`:

```js
console.log(StyleSheet.flatten(styles(theme).button))
```

which prints the actual object with the `width` attribute. However, this is not needed and this is also not the reason why your style is not applied.

You are trying to use the `spread operator` to combine two styles into a single style object, but since StyleSheet just returns an id this does not work. We can test this by using `flatten` again.

```js
<Button
   style={{
     marginVertical: 5,
     ...StyleSheet.flatten(props.style)
   }}
>Test</Button>
```

You will notice that the above will now correctly work.

However, this is not the optimal way of combining two styles. We can achieve the same by using `combine` of styles using the `array notation` as follows.

```js
<Button
   style={[{marginVertical: 5}, props.style]}
>Test</Button>
```